# Improper result of SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, datetime, date, simpledateformat

I want to convert `Tue Jun 01 00:00:00 IST 112` into `01-JUN-2012`

I used

```
 Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(year, 6, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
     Date maxDate=new Date();
     maxDate=calendar.getTime();  
     calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
      SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mmm-yyyy");
       s.format(maxDate);
```

But I get `30-000-0112`

Comment: `m` denotes `minutes` not `month`. You need to use `MMM`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use  CAPITAL M for month,

```
 SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Also you are setting date first and then you are resetting calendar which I guess not what you want to do so may be you need to change it to as follows

```
Date maxDate=new Date();
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
maxDate=calendar.getTime();  
SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
s.format(maxDate);
```

**See**

- [`SimpleDateFormat` API doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: +1. really fast! documentation for [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: I still get 31-JUN-0112 ,why year is improper?

Answer (score 3):

Use capital MMM in date format as shown below -

```
  SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
```

Everything else is ok

```
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
     Date maxDate=new Date();
     maxDate=calendar.getTime();  
     calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, calendar.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)); 
     SimpleDateFormat s=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
     System.out.println(s.format(maxDate));
```

output would be - `06-Jul-2012`