# Parsing date gives month of 00

Tags: java, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Improper result of SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356109/improper-result-of-simpledateformat)

The following code outputs a date of 00/12/2010.  I can't figure out why the date string is parsed without exception but the month is set to 00.  I tried using a second argument to the SimpleDateFormat constructor of Locale.Enlgish for sanity's sake but that didn't help.  Any suggestions?

```
    String dateString = "12-OCT-10";
    SimpleDateFormat formatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
    Date date = formatFrom.parse(dateString);
    SimpleDateFormat formatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
    System.out.println(formatTo.format(date));
```

Comment: Your first stop should be [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Then [a search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wrong+month+simpledateformat+site%3Astackoverflow.com). :-)

Comment: Couldn't agree more.  I read the documentation and I'm aware that lowercase 'm' is for minutes which is why I use uppercase 'M' in the first SimpleDateFormat. I just goofed on the second one.  Stupid mistake.  Seriously wish I could delete this post.  Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 13):

The `mm` is for minute, use `MM`; see [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for details.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356109/improper-result-of-simpledateformat/  same issue

Comment: Geez, you gotta be kidding me.  I can't believe I did that and wasted an hour on this.  Thanks for being an extra set of eyes.