# How to get current date and add five working days in Java

Tags: java, date, datetime

I want two dates. 
1) Current date in MM/dd/yy format
2) Modified date which will be the adition of five business days(Mon-Fri) to current date and it should be in MMM dd, yyyy format.

So if my current is 9th june than currentDate should be 06/09/14 and modifiedDate should be Jun 13, 2014.

How to do this?

Comment: for format part of question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11356109/improper-result-of-simpledateformat

Comment: You should understand that this site will help you when you need a help with your code. But they can not do researches on-behalf of you? So try something and ask help for any trouble with code. Try to use JODA framwork [link](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)

Comment: @Meno reopened it, your link is probably more closer than what I marked initially, although business days can vary

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will add working days (Mon-Fri) and will present dates in the required format.

**UPDATED 6 Jul 2020**

1. Now custom days can be used as non working days (*see the list NON_BUSINESS_DAYS*)
2. Now even the past date can be calculated as well (*set businessDays as negative val*)

---

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

public class BusinessDateExamples {

    private static final List<Integer> NON_BUSINESS_DAYS = Arrays.asList(
                Calendar.SATURDAY,
                Calendar.SUNDAY
            );
    
    /**
     * Returns past or future business date
     * @param date starting date
     * @param businessDays number of business days to add/subtract
     *          <br/>note: set this as negative value to get past date
     * @return past or future business date by the number of businessDays value
     */
    public static Date businessDaysFrom(Date date, int businessDays) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        for (int i = 0; i < Math.abs(businessDays);) {
            // here, all days are added/subtracted
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, businessDays > 0 ? 1 : -1);
            
            // but at the end it goes to the correct week day.
            // because i is only increased if it is a week day
            if (!NON_BUSINESS_DAYS.contains(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK))){
                i++;
            }
        }
        return calendar.getTime();
    }
    
    public static void main(String...strings) {
        SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy ( MMM dd, yyyy )");
        
        Date date = new Date();
        int businessDays = 5;
        
        System.out.println(s.format(date));
        
        System.out.print("+ " + businessDays + " Business Days = ");
        System.out.println(s.format(businessDaysFrom(date, businessDays)));
        
        System.out.print("- " + businessDays + " Business Days = ");
        System.out.println(s.format(businessDaysFrom(date, -1 * businessDays)));
    }
}
```

---

```
    Date date=new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    date=calendar.getTime(); 
    SimpleDateFormat s;
    s=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    
    System.out.println(s.format(date));
    
    int days = 5;
    for(int i=0;i<days;)
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        //here even sat and sun are added
        //but at the end it goes to the correct week day.
        //because i is only increased if it is week day
        if(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)<=5)
        {
            i++;
        }

    }
    date=calendar.getTime(); 
    s=new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    System.out.println(s.format(date));
```

Ref : https://stackoverflow.com/a/15339851/3603806
and   https://stackoverflow.com/a/11356123/3603806

Comment: Some countries have working weeks Sunday-Thursday. As a naive solution this will work, but please be mindful of date-time-calendar edge cases. Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Workweek_and_weekend#Around_the_world

Comment: This solution considers Friday and Saturday as the weekend. Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK starts with Sunday (Sunday has value 1)

Comment: The method `businessDaysFrom()` contains an error. The second row should be `calendar.setTime(date);`

Comment: @Hassenboy You are right, I carried that from previous solution, missed to update it! Updated! Thanks

Comment: Why do i think that i++ in for loop is not ok and in general while loop should have been used if you do i++

Answer (score 9):

The notion of working days is not implemented in Java, it's too subject to interpretation (for example, many international companies have their own holidays). Code below uses `isWorkingDay()`, which only returns false for weekends - add your holidays there.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
        // cal now contains current date
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());

        // add the working days
        int workingDaysToAdd = 5;
        for (int i=0; i<workingDaysToAdd; i++)
            do {
                cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
            } while ( ! isWorkingDay(cal));
        System.out.println(cal.getTime());
    }

    private static boolean isWorkingDay(Calendar cal) {
        int dayOfWeek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if (dayOfWeek == Calendar.SUNDAY || dayOfWeek == Calendar.SATURDAY)
            return false;
        // tests for other holidays here
        // ...
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: I omitted formatting, see the other answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code sample to add dates. You may modify in order to you can only add business days.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(new Date());

    System.out.println(sdf1.format(calendar.getTime()));
    calendar.add(Calendar.DATE,6);
    System.out.println(sdf2.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Comment: I think you have a tiny mistake: he wanted to add 5 days and not 6...

Comment: Here you simply add 6 calendar days, regardless the fact if they are business days or not. So, this doesn't give any solution to the actual problem.