# Best way to handle Java Calendar with working days?

Tags: java, date, calendar

I need to implement a labor calendar able to count **working** days and, of course, natural days. The calendar must be able to handle national holidays and these days must be submitted by the user.
So, if I need to calculate the difference between two days the counting must ignore Saturdays, Sundays, and Holidays.

The Java class [Calendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), doesn't handle holidays or working days, so I need to make it by myself. I have think two possible ways:

## First way:

I could implement a new `Day` class which would have a boolean `isHoliday` to check if that is a working day or not, then create a new class with all the methods I'd need to handle/count the days.

#### Pros:

- **Easy to handle**
- **I can override/create methods like toString, toDate, etc...**

#### Cons:

- **Heavy** (Maybe?)

My doubt about this approach is how to store it. It'd mean to make 365 objects and store them in a `List`or `Linked List` and that's a lot of data to handle.

## Second way:

My second idea is to make it more simple. Create an array of `Strings` or [Dates](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) where I'd store the holidays.
Example `new ArrayList<String> freeDays = ["01/01/2019", "05/01/2019", "06/01/2019"...]` and with work with it using a new CalendarUtils class or something like that.

#### Pros:

- **More readable**
- **Light**

### Cons:

- **Hard to work with**

For me the first option looks better, however, I don't want to waste memory or use bad practices.

Which option looks better? Are there any third option?

Comment: There's a few other questions with ideas, e.g. these two and the others they link to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114155/how-to-get-current-date-and-add-five-working-days-in-java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10854119/calculate-business-days-including-holidays

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

**Never use `Date` or `Calendar` classes.** Those terribly troublesome old classes are now legacy, supplanted by the *java.time* classes, specifically `Instant` and `ZonedDateTime`. You may find `LocalDate` helpful too.

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Never use strings to represent date-time within your Java code. Use objects, the *java.time* classes.

When exchanging date-time values as text, always use the standard ISO 8601 formats. The *java.time* classes use these formats by default when parsing/generating strings. For a date that would be YYYY-MM-DD such as `2018-01-23`.

## `TemporalAdjuster` interface

To skip weekends, use the [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation found in the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

- [`nextWorkingDay`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#nextWorkingDay--)
- [`previousWorkingDay`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.html#previousWorkingDay--)

Example:

```
LocalDate                        // Represent a date-only value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone. 
.now(                            // Capture the current date. 
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" )  // Time zone required. For any given moment the date varies around the globe by zone. 
)
.with(                           // Invoke a `TemporalAdjuster` implementation. 
    org.threeten.extra.Temporals.nextWorkingDay() 
)                                // Returns a `LocalDate`. Using immutable objects pattern, producing a fresh object based on the values of another while leaving the original unaltered.
```

To skip holidays, you must write your own code. No two people, companies, or countries share the same definition of holidays.

You’ll need to define your own list of holidays. I suggest writing that as an implementation of [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) for working neatly with the *java.time* classes. Perhaps `nextBusinessDay` and `previousBusinessDay`. That *ThreeTen-Extra* project mentioned above is open-source, so look to there for code to guide you. And I vaguely recall posting one or more implementations of `TemporalAdjuster` myself here on Stack Overflow.

You might store those holiday dates in a database for persistence. And represent them at runtime in chronological order as a `List< LocalDate >`, sorted with `Collections.sort` and searching with [`Collections.binarySearch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List,T)). But beware of [thread-safety](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_safety). You’ll likely need to update that list during runtime. Writing while reading must be protected. Search for more info. And read the excellent book, [*Java Concurrency in Practice* by Brian Goetz et al.](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/127932)

You can combine your holiday-skipping code with weekend-skipping code. Use a search engine to find my Answers on weekend-skipping using `EnumSet` and `DayOfWeek` enum. (The search feature built into Stack Overflow unfortunately skews towards Questions while ignoring Answers.)

Search Stack Overflow. All of this has been asked and answered before.

Comment: Just what I needed to know. Thank you very much.